# How to accept JSON POST parameters as @RequestParam in Spring Servlet?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a `POST` servlet that should be called with `JSON` request. The following should work, but does not. What might be missing?

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String test(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String[] params) {
        return "name was: " + name;
    }
}
```

JSON POST:

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "params": [
      "first", "snd"
   ]
}
```

Result: name is always null. Why?

`"Response could not be created: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'name' is not present"`

Comment: use a @RequestBody parameter that will give the result

Comment: Creating a `@GetController` and sending it as a get-query string works, but I need POST + JSON.

Comment: @PawanPandey If I'd use `@RequestBody` on both parameters, I get an error: `"Response could not be created: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String MyServlet.test(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])" `

Comment: have a pojo class like mydata{name;params[];} and at controller write test(@RequestBody mydata) and check if the content type in request header is application/json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general I don't pass a request param in a POST method. Instead, I am using a DTO to pass it in the body like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/items", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addItem(@RequestBody ItemDTO itemDTO)
```

Then, you need to create the ItemDTO as a POJO with the necessary fields.

Comment: Is there not other chance? I'd like to prevent having to create a dto if possible (because I hope being able to make use of eg `@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "some")` on the POST parameters

Comment: You can do it using hashmap but you need to use `@RequestBody` to accept post parameters.

Comment: or else stringify the json and pass in query string of post url then get as @RequestParam in a map

Comment: Ok, as an alternative it's possible to just use `@RequestBody Map map`, `map.get("format"); map.get("params")`. This is more suitable if only a few parameters are passed as json, so no DTO is required here.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @stzoannos answer, if you do not want to create POJO for json object, you can use [google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to parse json into JsonObject class, which allow to work with parameters through same as get and set methods.

```
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
return "name is: " + jsonObj.get("name").getAsString();
```